# javascript regularer expression - how to simplify

Tags: javascript, regex

I am reading a javascript file which has few issues and I come across with a RegEx which looks like

```
/^(a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z){3}\d{3}|(a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z){3}(a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z){0,1}$/;
```

Firstly what it actually matches and how can I simplify it

Comment: Edit : Replace the alphabet part by [a-z] ;) `/^[a-z]{3}\d{3}|[a-z]{3}[a-z]{0,1}$/; 
`

Comment: @kaldoran: That will include `_`.

Comment: @kaldoran: nope. just `[a-z]`

Comment: ...  uhm, regex has character classes. for example `[a-z]{3}` to get 3 a to z characters. Those pipes are more used to seperate words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's functionally similar to:

```
/^([a-z]){3}\d{3}|([a-z]){3}([a-z]){0,1}$/;
```

This basically captures:

- From the start of the string
- 3 characters in the a-z range followed by 3 digits, or
- 3 characters in the a-z range followed by 0 or 1 character in the a-z range.

Comment: I don't think you need the `()` anymore since they where is in order to apply the `|`

Comment: @kaldoran: Depends on what they were using it for (e.g., were they use the capture group). If it had been a non-capturing group `(?:a|b|...)`, it would definitely be unnecessary.

Comment: @kaldoran: If they were being used as capture grops, you need'm.